# image names are different from docker-compose build

Tags: docker-compose

for example, my project directory is

```
project/
  - docker-compose.yml
  - Dockerfile
```

`docker-compose.yml` is

```
services:
  app1:
    build:
      context: .
      target: development
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

so if i run

`docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml build app1`

will generate an image `project_app`, but if i run

`docker-compose build`

the image name will be `project-app`.

my question is why is this happening and if there is any way to persist the name without changing `docker-compose.yml`?

```
docker-compose version 1.29.2
```

Comment: can you share you docker-compose file ?

Comment: hey @KhanhLeTran, the question is updated with more info. thx.

Comment: do you define ```image``` property in service app1 ?

Comment: image property is not necessary in the file?

Comment: Yah, it not necessary but when you define it, the image image will be generated by ```image``` property